# How to use templates while separating header and implementation files?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to implement a Template while separating the Header and Implementation file.

I'm getting this error when building the project:

> error C2955: 'Series': use of class template requires template
>   argument list

Header.h

```
#ifndef SERIES_H
#define SERIES

template <class T>
class Series {
    private:
        T var;

    public:
        Series(T v);
    };

#endif
```

Implementation.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

template <class T>
Series::Series(T v) {
    var = v;
    std::cout << var;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

int main() {
    Series<int> w(10);
}
```

The project builds successfully when everything is in one file

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: You have a typo in your include guard. Not related to the problem however.

Comment: Shouldn't `Series::Series(T v)` be `Series<T>::Series(T v)` I think this is what the error message is about.

Comment: @drescherjm, you got it. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I think it would count as a typo. Which are supposed to be closed as such.

Comment: Not related, but why are you able to separate the implementation? Or are you including the cpp at the end of the header?

Comment: I just ended up putting the implementation and header in the same .h file